# chrome.windows.create help

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How would I open a local html file that is located within a `chrome.windows.create`? also, is it possible to make the `chrome.windows.create` non scrollable, no toolbars, etc?

Comment: hrome.action setIcon

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What about:

```
chrome.windows.create({url: "local.html", type: "popup"});
```

I think it should understand local path, if not then:

```
chrome.windows.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL("local.html"), type: "popup"});
```

Comment: Great response, 1 comment, window.open will allow him to create a popop too, worth adding :)

Comment: what are other options if i want to show my page on fixed browser extension icon

Comment: @ThinkTank when I use `state: 'minimized',` as the property, it doesn't create a hidden window tab? any help? code here. [Code Example](https://pastebin.com/5WUZJVvy)

Comment: try `WindowState` instead of state they might have changed it refer this and see `WindowState` option
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/

Comment: How can I access `chrome.windows` as it's undefind on developer console

Comment: If I open it as popup I noticed is a different window... How can I refresh the opener tab on the original window?

Comment: @DivyaSakariya [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28748527/3552975) may help.

Answer (score 0):

The question includes an "etc." that **might** mean you want no title bar for the window. If so, the answer is that it cannot be done. According to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create, there is no way to eliminate the title bar (probably to prevent phishing and other fraud). This was not the answer I wanted, since I wanted to write an extension to display a tiny digital clock, but I think it is true: a tiny popup digital clock extension is impossible. An attempt to set an option called "frame" to "none" only generates an error message.

Comment: when I use `state: 'minimized',` as the property, it doesn't create a hidden window tab? any help? code here. [Code Example](https://pastebin.com/5WUZJVvy)

Comment: Thank you, but I couldn't get your Pastebin example to run in Pastebin. But wouldn't it just create a minimized window? How is this good for making a tiny digital clock?

Comment: i just want a window to be created and hidden in the background via the extension, so i can do stuff then close this hidden window, I'm automating some functions for a user.

Comment: I believe that windows can only be created visibly in extensions, so there would be a "flash" of the window seen by the user. One solution is to write a C or C++ program to display a window any way you like. You would call this executable in your program, unless you are using JavaScript, which would be more difficult due to its limited functionality to ensure security. You can also look into browser application frameworks like Neutron and Neutralino.