# chrome.windows undefined for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension that allows the user to manage open tabs for an application (website). The manifest is:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "AT Tabs",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs"],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["main.js"]
    }]
}
```

But when I do this in the main.js file:

`console.log(chrome.windows);`

I get undefined in the console... Any ideas why? I have both tabs and activeTab as permissions and the extension is being run in the developer mode.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`chrome.windows` will not be available in your `main.js` because it is an injected content script.

Only your [background/event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) JavaScript has access to `chrome.windows`. You will need to use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) from your content script to your background script to trigger the window actions you want.

For instance, to create a window from an content script, your extension may look something like this:

Manifest:

```
{
  ...
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  ...
}
```

main.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: 'createWindow',
    url: 'http://google.com'
  },
  function(createdWindow) {
    console.log(createdWindow);
  });
```

eventPage.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request && request.action === 'createWindow' && request.url) {
    chrome.windows.create({url: request.url}, function (win) {
      sendResponse(win);
    });
  }
});
```